How to write a function that simulates particle collisions in cellular automata?
I wish to write a function that outputs something like this page's 6th figure, which simulates particle collisions in rule 110. Here is the code for reference
With[{bkg = ResourceData["Persistent Structures in Rule 110", All]["Background"], 
collisions = Normal@ResourceData["Persistent Structures in Rule 110", All]["Collisions"]}, 
ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[110, #, {270, 200 + {-100, 100}}], 
ImageSize -> {140, Automatic}] & /@ collisions[[1, "InitialConditions"]]]

I want to change the initial conditions, as well as to input some sort of perturbation (like a wall) to analyze the particle's behavior, and change the rule if possible. I am not sure how to modify the code to do so

What have you tried? How didn't that work?

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know how to modify it

I suggest you start by taking the [tour], and read the [ask] help, and what questions are on topic. Notice that we expect some minimal Mathematica knowledge and you honest minimal due diligence.
